# Getting compile error: argument type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Option Explicit

Sub data()

Dim a, b As String

a = "demo"
b = "text"    

Call getValue(a, b)

End Sub


Sub getValue(a As String, b As String)    

Cells(1, 1).Value = a
Cells(1, 2).Value = b

End Sub
```

---

I am getting compile time error: byref argument type mismatch error on above code

Answer (score 6):

When you define `Dim a, b As String` it means **only** `b As String` while `a As Variant`. You need to define the type explicitly for each variable you define.

Modify your line to: `Dim a As String, b As String`, and it will work.